# Unity: How to create a selection box around gameObjects (Text or images) similar to those in Unity editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my Unity app, the user has the option to input text and import images. I have implemented these using TMP_Input Field and Image/Sprites respectively. The app also requires that the user knows the currently selected text/image and can also drag these text and images and sometimes resize them.

To achieve this what I need is a UI like this.

[image]

This is the actual Unity editor. But I want to have similar box around my text and images in my app. So that the user knows the current selection and may also drag the text/Image or resize it using the blue circles in the corners.

I am not sure how I can achieve this. One way which I see is to have views which wrap my text and images and these views will have these boxes as the backgrounds.

But I thought that there may be an easier way to do this, probably something that comes with Unity since this looks like a general requirement to me. I am not sure though. What would be the best way to achieve this? WIll I have to do everything from scratch or are there any existing UI components or assets which can make this easier? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to make a component, all you would need is a couple of this line sprites and circle sprites for the corners than are positioned on the edges and corners respectively when it is selected and make them draggable and that drag update is then used to update the Recttransform

Comment: Depending on how deep you want to get into it and your target platform you could maybe even use the [MoxedRealityToolkit `BoundingBox`](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_BoundingBox.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to take a look at this and came up with a solution.

Each Resizable element has 4 line images and 4 corner images.

Each corner has this script attached to it to make it draggable and to send its position change when being dragged to the main ResizableElement script.

```cs
public class ResizableElementDraggable : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{

#pragma warning disable 0649
    [SerializeField] private ResizableElement _resizableElement;
    [SerializeField] private ResizableElementCorners _corner;
#pragma warning restore 0649

    private Vector2 _lastKnownPosition;
    private void Awake()
    {
        _lastKnownPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void IDragHandler.OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        _resizableElement.UpdateSize(_corner, _lastKnownPosition - eventData.position);
    }

    public void UpdatePosition()
    {
        _lastKnownPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

The main ResizableElement script is as follows which includes the public enum to easily see which corner is sending the position change.

```cs
public enum ResizableElementCorners
{
    TopLeft,
    TopRight,
    BottomLeft,
    BottomRight
}

public class ResizableElement : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
#pragma warning disable 0649
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _lines;
    [SerializeField] private ResizableElementDraggable[] _corners;
#pragma warning disable 0649

    private RectTransform _rectTransform;
    public bool IsSelected { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        _rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    public void UnSelect()
    {
        if (IsSelected)
        {
            IsSelected = false;
            for (int l = 0; l < _lines.Length; l++)
            {
                _lines[l].SetActive(false);
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < _lines.Length; c++)
            {
                _corners[c].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Select()
    {
        if (!IsSelected)
        {
            IsSelected = true;
            for (int l = 0; l < _lines.Length; l++)
            {
                _lines[l].SetActive(true);
            }
            for (int c = 0; c < _lines.Length; c++)
            {
                _corners[c].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateSize(ResizableElementCorners corner, Vector2 change)
    {
        Vector2 offsetMin = _rectTransform.offsetMin;
        Vector2 offsetMax = _rectTransform.offsetMax;

        switch (corner)
        {
            case ResizableElementCorners.TopLeft:
                _rectTransform.offsetMax = new Vector2(offsetMax.x, offsetMax.y - change.y);
                _rectTransform.offsetMin = new Vector2(offsetMin.x - change.x, offsetMin.y);
                break;
            case ResizableElementCorners.TopRight:
                _rectTransform.offsetMax = new Vector2(offsetMax.x - change.x, offsetMax.y - change.y);
                break;
            case ResizableElementCorners.BottomLeft:
                _rectTransform.offsetMin = new Vector2(offsetMin.x - change.x, offsetMin.y - change.y);

                break;
            case ResizableElementCorners.BottomRight:
                _rectTransform.offsetMax = new Vector2(offsetMax.x - change.x, offsetMax.y);
                _rectTransform.offsetMin = new Vector2(offsetMin.x, offsetMin.y - change.y);
                break;
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < _lines.Length; c++)
        {
            _corners[c].UpdatePosition();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Select();
    }
}
```

It uses the `OnPointerClick` to know when it has been selected- you will need to track these elements and send to unselect others on this trigger but for this demo I didn't add it.

I have created a demo project and uploaded it to Github and it can be found [here](https://github.com/iambase/ResizableUI)

Disclaimer - this is just a demo

**Update:**

I have made a basic asset package that includes 2 prefabs a ResizableUI main script holder that controls the ResizableObjects in the Scene and a Prefab that when added as a child to any UI object with a RectTransform makes it a Resizable Element.

There are a couple of basic settings that can be set on each Resizable element including Resize Directions, min size and locking corners.

The whole project is being hosted in the [Git Repo](https://github.com/iambase/ResizableUI).

Hope someone finds it useful.

**Update 2**

I rewrote the project and it has now become a fully fledged component, once the required scripts (4) are in the project, all thats needed is to add a `ResizableUIComponent` to the desired UI Element to make it in app resizable.

To tailor it it has a few settings, corner tabs sprite and color, and the outline width and color.

If you come across this looking for something check out the [repo](https://github.com/iambase/ResizableUI) for more info.